# replay button in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making an e-learning module with multiple frames.

I want to add a refreshbutton, so that a user can reload a frame (with a movieclip), so that he or she can watch it again. I use one layer where I place all my actions.

I tried, the following, but that doesn't work

```
refresh_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, goToCurrentPageHandler) ;
function goToCurrentPageHandler (event:MouseEvent) : void
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    gotoAndPlay();
```

I also tried:

```
/*refresh_button*/  
refresh_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, goToCurrentPageHandler) ;
function goToCurrentPageHandler (event:MouseEvent) : void
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    gotoAndPlay(currentFrame);
```

But when I press the refresh button it starts playing the next frame.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gotoAndPlay(currentFrame);
```

actually plays the next one because you are saying "get the current position and start playing from there". Your sound is in a movie clip called *frame_1*. So you should use:

```
frame_1.gotoAndPlay(1);
```

I.e. your code should look like that:

```
/*refresh_button*/  
refresh_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, goToCurrentPageHandler) ;
function goToCurrentPageHandler (event:MouseEvent) : void
{
    SoundMixer.stopAll();
    frame_1.gotoAndPlay(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I tried that also, but I get the same problem. Do I have to place the code in the main timeline? Won't it always go to frame 1, even if I am on frame 2 and replay it?

Comment: If you type gotoAndPlay(1); it will always go to the first frame. However I don't know your movie clips tree and can't say what exactly gotoAndPlay refers to. Is refresh_btn in the same movie which you want to control.

Comment: I have on layer with all my actions for the "next button", "mute button" etc. I have a layer that has multiple frames with my movieclips and I have several layers with the buttons (like the next button and mute button). Can I send you the flash-file?

Comment: Yep. Send it to info @ krasimirtsonev.com

Comment: Find the answer above.

Comment: Ok I will try this. Should I place this code on every refresh_btn frame?

Answer (score 1):

without refreshing you can try simply insert stop button function inside play buttons function then no need to refresh you should first stop sound chaneel sc inorder to close sound s . then disable and enable play and stop buttons by //object..mouseEnabled = false; , //object..mouseEnabled = true;

```
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

btn_play.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, PlayStream);




var sc: SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
var s: Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("folder/song .mp3"));

function PlayStream(event: MouseEvent): void {

sc = s.play();
btn_play.mouseEnabled = false;
btn_stop.mouseEnabled = true;

      btn_stop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, StopStream);

          function StopStream(event: MouseEvent): void {
          SoundMixer.stopAll();
          sc.stop();
          s.close();
          btn_play.mouseEnabled = true;
          btn_stop.mouseEnabled = false;
          }

}

stop();
```